# How to rerender a component in Vue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a sidebar consisted of three tabs:

```
Home Users List
```

When I click the 'Users' tab, Router will transition like this:

```
this.$router.push('index/users')
```

and then the Users component will be rendered in:

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

Now I want to click the Users tab again in order to fetch latest data.But the component won't re-render again, and the data doesn't refresh.

Are there any other ways I can resolve it instead of F5? 
I hope it works for all of the components.
PS: I fetch data in the lifecycle hook created().

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/296#issuecomment-235481643

Comment: thanks Ricky, helpful information.

Comment: Here's a plugin developed following that comment instructions. https://gist.github.com/fnlctrl/1cf9da63493e0fe78181a4f4e2cc6f64

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved by watching the router for change in the component to "reload": https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

```
  watch: {
      '$route': 'fetchData'  // call the function which update data
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

As far i know, vuejs router doesn't support refresh the componnet while connecting same route . But i am giving a simple way using `location.reload()` as follows

```
this.$router.push('index/users')
location.reload()
```

Comment: It works, but looks very ugly...  I just want to refresh the component instead of the whole page...

Comment: Yeah its ugly :(